# Can not run the command "adb reverse" because it does not exists

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I am trying to run my react-native app on android. the documentation says I need to run "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081"

but my adb (version 1.0.31) does not have a "reverse" command.

also the adb documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#commandsummary) is not mentioning this command.

did they remove it? is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm, Ok, it looks like version 1.0.31 is just too old. And it also looks like the official documentation is completely out of date.

I had 1.0.31 installed because I installed it via apt-get

The version that was installed by Android Studio is version 1.0.36 and that one also has the reverse command.

Comment: i also had this exact problem, so if i install 1.0.36 version it has adb reverse? mine now was 1.0.31

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, so I went to the location of adb at:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

I ran the command and it worked.